# Automatically check data on mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm building a web-based admin which has membership plans. Each plan have its different longevity which means they have expiration dates.

On my MySQL database I have a table named `transactions` that has columns like `start_date` and `expiry_date`.

Now my question is, how will the web or the database automatically check the table if the `expiry_date` column is equal to date `now()` even if the **ADMIN** is not online?

Is that even possible? Answers would be so much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cron is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Or, you can set up [triggers](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx) !

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I'm using [freemysqlhosting.net] as my online database and it has no event triggers option. :(

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking for here since it would be a very simple query to compare expiry date to now(). If you want to update the db on expiry date then you should say so in the question.BTW you should probably research mysql events.And if your provider does not allow triggers or events then they are probably not the provider you need.